# How to apply discount to basket line?

Tags: django, django-oscar

New to Django-oscar and can't have answers on the official docs
I'm trying to add a discount
I tried this:

```
line, created = self.request.basket.add_product(product=product, quantity=serializer.validated_data['quantity'], options=options)
line.discount(discount_value=20, affected_quantity=1)
line.save()
```

and when I try to print `basket.total_excl_tax_excl_discounts` or `basket.total_excl_tax` I always get the same result (which is the total of basket no matter discounts I added)

what am I missing ??

Comment: Please post the code where you're trying to access the basket total - is it in the same view? Note also that line discounts are stored as instance variables on the object, meaning they do not persist across requests. You ideally should use the offer applicator to apply discounts consistently, rather than manually modifying lines yourself.

Comment: @solarissmoke now when creating the order i get cannot calculate total_incl_tax as tax is not know
although i have provided price_incl_tax in the basket line .. any ideas?

Comment: @solarissmoke yes i'm getting the basket total in another request, in this case what can i do? also how to use offer applicator? couldn't find in the docs

Comment: Please see https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/ref/apps/offer.html for an introduction to offers. This is a broad topic and one that I think you will probably have to spend some time understanding - but basically you need to create an offer that provides the discount you want, and let Oscar apply that to the basket instead of applying discounts manually.